# How to get concurrency when using AsyncLines

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I'm trying to use `AsyncLineSequence` with `Process` to execute many instances of a shell script at the same time. The issue I'm seeing is that with my usage of `AsyncLineSequence` I'm not seeing the output of the `Process` invocations interweaved like I would expect. It feels like there is something fundamental I am misunderstanding as this seems like it should work to me.

Here's a reproduction in a playground

```swift
import Cocoa

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}

func run(label: String) throws {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/yes")
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    Task {
        for try await _ in pipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines {
            print(label)
        }
    }

    try process.run()
}

Task {
    try run(label: "a")
}

Task {
    try run(label: "b")
}
```

The above will print only `a` or `b` but never both. If I change to not use `AsyncLineSequence` like this

```swift
import Cocoa

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}

func run(label: String) throws {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/yes")
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe

    pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { _ in
        print(label)
    }

    try process.run()
}

Task {
    try run(label: "a")
}

Task {
    try run(label: "b")
}
```

The `a`s and `b`s are both printed interleaved.

To add to my confusion if I use URLSession to get async lines by reading an arbitrary file it does interleave the print statements of `a` and `b` as I'd expect

```swift
import Cocoa

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}

Task {
    for try await _ in try await URLSession.shared.bytes(from: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/yes")).0.lines {
        print("a")
    }
}

Task {
    for try await _ in try await URLSession.shared.bytes(from: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/yes")).0.lines {
        print("b")
    }
}
```

If I replace `URLSession` for `FileHandle` in the above then I am back to no interleaving and all of one file is read followed by the next

```swift
import Cocoa

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)
}

Task {
    for try await _ in try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/yes")).bytes.lines {
        print("a")
    }
}

Task {
    for try await _ in try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/yes")).bytes.lines {
        print("b")
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn’t personally advise using Playgrounds for these sorts of diagnostics. Playgrounds are a somewhat idiosyncratic environment, and I would hesitate to draw any broad performance/thread-related conclusions from Playground results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I did this (10 seconds rather than 2 seconds, and in an app rather than a Playground), I *do* see them jumping back and forth.

Admittedly, it was not one-for-one interleaving (it was lots of “a”s followed by lots of “b”s, and then the process repeats). But there is no reason it would interleave perfectly one-for-one between the two processes, because while `lines` emits an asynchronous sequence of lines, behind the scenes it is likely reading chunks of output from the pipe, not really consuming it line by line, which would be very inefficient. (And, IMHO, it’s interesting that the `URLSession` behavior is different, but not terribly surprising.) And you effectively have two processes racing, so there is no reason to expect a graceful, alternating, behavior between the two.

If you replace `yes` with a program that waits a little between lines of output (e.g., I had it wait for 0.01 seconds between each line of output), then you will see it interleave a bit more frequently. Or when I added an actor to keep track which process last emitted a line of output, that was enough to trigger an immediate back-and-forth processing of one line from each `yes` output alternatively.

You might also want to consider the implication of running these two loops with `Task { ... }`, as that [will run](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/init(priority:operation:)-5ltye) each “operation asynchronously as part of a new top-level task on behalf of *the current actor*” [emphasis added]. You might consider detached tasks or separate actors (to reduce contention on the current actor handling both loops). In my tests, it did not change the results too dramatically, but your mileage may vary. Regardless, it is something to be aware of.

Comment: Interesting notes thanks. The example was just a reduction of what I was seeing and hopefully giving a starting point for any debugging. I wasn't looking for a strict interleaving of output but just some interleaving, which you seemed to see with a longer time. The full use case I had was triggering two processes to build docker images - with this I only ever saw one process' output. I'm fairly sure I tried detached tasks but I'll give that a go and see if it was contention like you say and report back

Comment: I finally revisited this!! The bit you said about adding a sleep in the called program was interesting - I ended up adding `await Task.yield()` in my `lines` loop which allowed things to behave as expected. My real life example is invoking docker commands (which I don't control so can't throttle it's output easily) so it's almost like both the `lines` sequences are being iterated on the same executor blocking each other from making forward progress unless they yield time, which is unintuitive to me (same result if I detach tasks).